# Terminal command to enable / disable Stage Manager in the new System Settings in macOS Ventura

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, stage-manager

I am trying to write **an automation** using either Bash or AppleScript, **to enable / disable Stage Manager**, and this looks quite difficult to achieve.

I cannot find much documentation around since in macOS Ventura the System Preferences have become System Settings, and there are not tabs anymore, so I ask whether anyone is able to achieve the task.

It looks like I have found a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001145/enabling-voice-control-in-applescript-ventura#new-answer).  However I have difficulties in pointing at the right Switch. Here is my script which does not work. It looks like I am having the groups messed up...

```
do shell script "open x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Desktop-Settings.extension"

tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "System Settings"
        repeat until UI element 4 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of ¬
          group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Desktop & Dock" exists
            delay 0.1
          end repeat
            
          click checkbox "Stage Manager" of group 6 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Desktop & Dock"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 5):

To disable Stage Manager:

`defaults write com.apple.WindowManager GloballyEnabled -bool false`

To enable it:

`defaults write com.apple.WindowManager GloballyEnabled -bool true`